# Reading height value from the heightmap

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying read the height from the heightmap on both CPU and GPU, but I receive two different values. I loaded the heightmap as both image data on CPU and texture on GPU using:

```
vd::img::IMGLoader imgLoader;
heightImg = imgLoader.loadFloatImage(tokens[0]);

heightMap = vd::model::TextureService::get(tokens[0]);
heightMap->bind();
heightMap->bilinearFilter();
heightMap->unbind();
```

Where tokens[0] is the path to the heightmap on disk, loadFloatImage implementation:

```
ImageFPtr stbiIMGLoader::loadFloatImage(const std::string& path)
{
    int x, y, n;
    int force_channels = 4;
    unsigned char* image_data = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &x, &y, &n, force_channels);
    if (!image_data)
    {
        vd::Logger::warn("Could not load " + path);
        return nullptr;
    }

    if ((x & (x - 1)) != 0 || (y & (y - 1)) != 0)
    {
        vd::Logger::log("Texture " + path + " is not power-of-2 dimension");
    }

    ImageF _img(x, y);

    size_t len = x * y * 4;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 4)
    {
        float r = ((float)image_data[i] / 255.0f);
        float g = ((float)image_data[i + 1] / 255.0f);
        float b = ((float)image_data[i + 2] / 255.0f);
        float a = ((float)image_data[i + 3] / 255.0f);
        PixelF pixel(r, g, b, a);
        _img.expand(pixel);
    }
    stbi_image_free(image_data);

    ImageFPtr imagePtr = std::make_shared<ImageF>(_img);

    imagePtr->reverse();

    return imagePtr;
}
```

Here, I created a wrapper over the Image, basically, it has an std::vector of Pixels (4 floats with values inside [0.0, 1.0]). The expand method is just pushing back to the vector, and the reverse method is flipping the image horizontally. The TextureService class is doing the same thing, but loading a byte image (each pixel containing 4 bytes with values inside {0, 1, ..., 255}). After loading the image, it creates a texture using

```
glGenTextures(1, &id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_SRGB_ALPHA, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &(imagePtr->data[0]));

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

After loading the texture, that `bilinearFilter` just switch the MIN and MAG filter to GL_LINEAR.

On CPU, I use the following method to compute the height value for an (x, z) pair:

```
float TerrainConfig::getHeight(float x, float z) const {
    float upperBound = scaleXZ / 2.0f;
    float lowerBound = -upperBound;

    if (x < lowerBound || z < lowerBound || x >= upperBound || z >= upperBound)
        return 0.0f;

    // reverse transform
    float rx = (x + (scaleXZ / 2.0f)) / scaleXZ;
    float rz = (z + (scaleXZ / 2.0f)) / scaleXZ;

    const auto height = vd::img::ImageHelper::texture(*heightImg, glm::vec2(rz, rx)).r;

    return height * scaleY;
}
```

With the texture method implementation:

```
Pixel<T> ImageHelper::texture(const Image<T>& image, const glm::vec2& uv) {
    glm::vec2 uvCoords = uv;

    if (uvCoords.x < 0.0f || uvCoords.x > 1.0f || uvCoords.y < 0.0f || uvCoords.y    > 1.0f) {
       vd::Logger::warn("UV coords exceed image, down sampling to accepted values");

       uvCoords.x -= std::floor(uvCoords.x);
       uvCoords.y -= std::floor(uvCoords.y);
    }

    float uv_x = uvCoords.x * (image.width - 1);
    float uv_y = uvCoords.y * (image.height - 1);

    int uv_x_0 = int(std::floor(uv_x));
    int uv_y_0 = int(std::floor(uv_y));
    int uv_x_1 = uv_x_0 + 1;
    int uv_y_1 = uv_y_0 + 1;

    if ((std::abs(uv_x - std::floor(uv_x)) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() &&
         std::abs(uv_y - std::floor(uv_y)) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()) ||
         (uv_x_1 >= image.width || uv_y_1 >= image.height))
    {
        return image.at(uv_x_0, uv_y_0);
    }

    Pixel<T> v0 = image.at(uv_x_0, uv_y_0);
    Pixel<T> v1 = image.at(uv_x_0, uv_y_1);
    Pixel<T> v2 = image.at(uv_x_1, uv_y_0);
    Pixel<T> v3 = image.at(uv_x_1, uv_y_1);

    float frac_x = uv_x - float(uv_x_0);
    float frac_y = uv_y - float(uv_y_0);


    Pixel<T> v01(
        glm::mix(v0.r, v1.r, frac_x),
        glm::mix(v0.g, v1.g, frac_x),
        glm::mix(v0.b, v1.b, frac_x),
        glm::mix(v0.a, v1.a, frac_x)
    );

    Pixel<T> v23(
        glm::mix(v2.r, v3.r, frac_x),
        glm::mix(v2.g, v3.g, frac_x),
        glm::mix(v2.b, v3.b, frac_x),
        glm::mix(v2.a, v3.a, frac_x)
    );

    return Pixel<T>(
        glm::mix(v01.r, v23.r, frac_y),
        glm::mix(v01.g, v23.g, frac_y),
        glm::mix(v01.b, v23.b, frac_y),
        glm::mix(v01.a, v23.a, frac_y)
    );
}
```

Here, I tried to implement the equivalent of the GLSL texture method. I am not sure this is the best approach.

Moving to the terrain, I am using a quadtree structure, for debugging purposes, I only kept the root nodes (32x32). Each root node is rendering a patch of 16 vertices and for each node, I compute a model matrix to translate the patch to the root node position inside the terrain (obtaining vertices with values inside [0.0, 1.0]) and for the whole terrain I apply a model matrix to transform the patch into my desired mesh (I translate it to the (-scaleXZ/2, 0.0f, -scaleXZ/2) in order to have the (x: 0, z: 0) coordinate in the center, and I scale it by (scaleXZ, scaleY, scaleXZ).

After all is set and done, I implemented the following pipeline:
VS:

```
#version 430

layout (location = 0) in vec2 vPosition;

out vec2 tcTexCoords;

uniform mat4 localModel;
uniform mat4 worldModel;

void main() {
    // Compute local coordinates
    vec2 localCoords = (localModel * vec4(vPosition.x, 0.0f, vPosition.y, 1.0f)).xz;

    // Pass texcoords
    tcTexCoords = localCoords;

    // Compute world coordinates
    vec4 worldCoords = worldModel * vec4(localCoords.x, 0.0f, localCoords.y, 1.0f);

    // Set vertex position
    gl_Position = worldCoords;
}
```

TCS:

```
#version 430

layout (vertices = 16) out;

in vec2 tcTexCoords[];
out vec2 teTexCoords[];

uniform float tessellationOuterLevel;
uniform float tessellationInnerLevel;

/*
               D        Outer[3] / CD      C
            (0, 1) -------------------- (1, 1)
               |                           |
               |                           |
               |                           |
 Outer[0] / DA |                           | Outer[2] / BC
               |                           |
               |                           |
               |                           |
            (0, 0) -------------------- (1, 0)
               A        Outer[1] / AB      B
*/

// patch edges indices
const int AB = 1;
const int BC = 2;
const int CD = 3;
const int DA = 0;

void main() {
    // control only the first call
    if (gl_InvocationID == 0) {
        gl_TessLevelOuter[AB] = tessellationOuterLevel;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[BC] = tessellationOuterLevel;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[CD] = tessellationOuterLevel;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[DA] = tessellationOuterLevel;

        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = tessellationInnerLevel;
        gl_TessLevelInner[1] = tessellationInnerLevel;
    }

    teTexCoords[gl_InvocationID] = tcTexCoords[gl_InvocationID];
    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
}
```

TES:

```
#version 430

layout (quads, equal_spacing) in;

in vec2 teTexCoords[];
out vec2 gTexCoords;

uniform float patchHeights[16];

uniform sampler2D heightMap;
uniform float scaleY;

void main() {
    float u = gl_TessCoord.x;
    float v = gl_TessCoord.y;

    while (patchHeights[0] == 0.0f) break;

    // using corners of the patch, we can compute the position
    // 0 = bottom left, 3 = bottom right, 12 = top left, 15 = top right
    // vec4 v0 = vec4(gl_in[0].gl_Position.x, patchHeights[0], gl_in[0].gl_Position.z, 1.0f);
    // vec4 v3 = vec4(gl_in[3].gl_Position.x, patchHeights[3], gl_in[3].gl_Position.z, 1.0f);
    // vec4 v12 = vec4(gl_in[12].gl_Position.x, patchHeights[12], gl_in[12].gl_Position.z, 1.0f);
    // vec4 v15 = vec4(gl_in[15].gl_Position.x, patchHeights[15], gl_in[15].gl_Position.z, 1.0f);
    vec4 v0 = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    vec4 v3 = gl_in[3].gl_Position;
    vec4 v12 = gl_in[12].gl_Position;
    vec4 v15 = gl_in[15].gl_Position;

    vec4 position = (
        (1 - u) * (1 - v) * v15 +
        u * (1 - v) * v3 +
        u * v * v0 +
        (1 - u) * v * v12
    );

    vec2 texCoords = (
        (1 - u) * (1 - v) * teTexCoords[15] +
        u * (1 - v) * teTexCoords[3] +
        u * v * teTexCoords[0] +
        (1 - u) * v * teTexCoords[12]
    );

    position.y = texture(heightMap, texCoords).r * scaleY;

    gTexCoords = texCoords;
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Here, I used patchHeights to send via uniform height values read on CPU. It worked that way, but the problem is that interpolating heights, the terrain looks ugly with very sharp peaks and straight hills.

And in the last step, I use GS to apply the ProjectionView matrix to the gl_Position:

```
#version 430

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
....
void main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); ++i) {
        vec4 worldCoords = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        vec4 eyeSpaceCoords = view * worldCoords;
        gl_Position = projection * eyeSpaceCoords;
        ....
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of changes such as: swapping XY with YX on texCoords, swapping coordinates on getHeight method, as seen sending via uniform the heights, reading the height on VS, and let the TES interpolate it, but nothing seems to work as I wanted.

An interesting fact that I discovered, is that I am using the same heightmap to compute the splatmap. I am using a Compute Shader to do it, so I use the GLSL texture to read from the heightmap. I set the scaleY to 160 and I created some intervals, [0, 7.5] - sand, [7.5, 45.0] - grass1, [45.0, 95.0] - grass2,
[95.0, 143.0] - rock1, [143.0, 160.0] - rock2, and the splatmap is computed correctly, but in-app, I cannot see the last material because the maximum elevation of the terrain reaches ~111, but the player object (which uses my texture implementation on CPU to read the height in the exact same spot) reaches ~140. If I move around with the player it seems like the player follows the terrain elevation but it is shifted upwards with some value. When I finally reach the height of 0.0 both CPU and GPU returns 0, so from here I assume that it is not a translation on Y-axis for the terrain.

*Player elevation ~140, terrain ~111*
[image: player elevation ~140, terrain ~111]

*Moving down the hill, it follows the terrain elevation, but with some offset*
[image: moving down the hill, it follows the terrain elevation, but with some offset]

*At 0 height, both CPU and GPU returns 0*
[image: at 0 height, both CPU and GPU returns 0]

TL;DR: I am trying to read the height value from the heightmap on CPU (using a method I implemented) and returns a different value compared to the GPU (using the GLSL texture method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @Rabbid76's comment:

> Why do you use the internal format `GL_SRGB_ALPHA` for the height map?

That is spot-on.  Using an sRGB format will lead to a non-linear remapping of your texture values at sample time. As by the [definition of the sRGB color space](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/Color/sRGB), the mapping is:

```
        / x / 12.92                      if x <= 0.04045
f(x) = {
        \ ((x + 0.055) / 1.055)^2.4      otherwise
```

In your example, you stated that on a texture with scale of 160, you get ~140 on CPU and ~111 on GPU, which translates to normalized values of `0.875` and `0.69`, respectively. If `0.875` is stored in the texture, than above sRGB conversion will yield `0.739` (or around 118 in your scaled height). That's still a bit off, so I'm not sure if your numbers are to imprecise or something else is amiss, but the sRGB conversion is certainly a huge factor in your offsets.

Using sRGB texture formats is useful first and foremost when you want to store "usual" RGB color image data with a precision of 8 Bit, but want to do for example lighting calculations in a physically linear color space. It might come handy for some other types of data too, if you basically need more precision near 0 and a lot less precision towards 1, but I don't think that this is desirable for standard heightfield data (and even if you want to use it for that, you need to inversly pre-transform the linear height values before you put them into the texture).